# how to use ajax datepicker in vb.net 2.0

Tags: ajax

Can I have good **example** or **code** about how to use **Ajax Datepicker** in my **vb.net** 2.0?

Please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a [jQuery UI DatePicker instead of AJAX Control Toolkit CalendarExtender in ASP.NET](http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2009/05/04/jQuery-UI-DatePicker-instead-of-AJAX-Control-Toolkit-CalendarExtender-in-ASPNET.aspx)

Comment: Can you please give me some reasons why you are not interested using Ajax Control Toolkit CalenderExtender in ASP.NET? Please suggest

Comment: Did you check the post? Well … the speed, the options, the themes, the frequent updates, the ease of integration, etc. . Taken from the post.

Comment: Thanks, can you please guide me how to implement JQuery UI Datepicker in application.